# Changing background according to time - Objective C

Tags: time, background, compare, nsdate, nscalendar

So what I'm trying to do is change the background of an image according to the time of day, but it's running into a problem. Here's the code:

```
-(void)updateBackground
{
    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *resultTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];
    [timeLabel setText:resultTime];
    NSString *morningStart = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"05:00 AM"];
    NSString *morningEnd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"11:59 AM"];
    NSString *afternoonStart = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"12:00 PM"];
    NSString *afternoonEnd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"02:59 PM"];
    NSString *eveningStart = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"03:00 PM"];
    NSString *eveningEnd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"07:59 PM"];
    NSString *nightStart = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"08:00 PM"];
    NSString *nightEnd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"04:59 AM"];
    NSLog(resultTime);
    if ([resultTime compare:morningStart]==NSOrderedDescending) {
        if ([resultTime compare:morningEnd]==NSOrderedAscending) {
            UIImage *morning = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MorningTime.jpeg"];
            [background setImage:morning];
        }
    }
    if ([resultTime compare:afternoonStart]==NSOrderedDescending) {
        if ([resultTime compare:afternoonEnd]==NSOrderedAscending) {
            UIImage *afternoon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"afternoonSky.jpeg"];
            [background setImage:afternoon];
        }
    }
    if ([resultTime compare:eveningStart]==NSOrderedDescending) {
        if ([resultTime compare:eveningEnd]==NSOrderedAscending) {
            UIImage *evening = [UIImage imageNamed:@"EveningSky.jpeg"];
            [background setImage:evening];
        }
    }
    if ([resultTime compare:nightStart]==NSOrderedDescending) {
        if ([resultTime compare:nightEnd]==NSOrderedAscending) {
            UIImage *night = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NightSky.jpeg"];
            [background setImage:night];
        }
    }


}
```

So what the problem is, let's say it's 11:54 PM, but it keeps saying that it's after 5:00 AM and before 11:59 AM! It's not choosing the right if statement! What do I do?

Comment: You are comparing the strings. You should really compare the NSDate objects.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson Could you please give me a link that is similar to mine?

Comment: sorry I have no link to such code. I have written an answer instead ;-) It does not contain full source code, but rather hints on how to implement what you are looking for.

Comment: Could you please select the preferred answer?

Answer (score 0):

NSDate format gives the time in 24 hours format so you have to change the time like (01:00 AM,13:00 PM )for placing conditions whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

may be this one helps you,

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *resultTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];
    NSString *morningStart = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"05:00 AM"];
    NSString *morningEnd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"11:59 AM"];
    NSString *afternoonStart = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"12:00 PM"];
    NSString *afternoonEnd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"14:59 PM"];
    NSString *eveningStart = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"15:00 PM"];
    NSString *eveningEnd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"19:59 PM"];
    if ([morningStart compare:resultTime]==NSOrderedAscending & [resultTime compare:morningEnd]==NSOrderedAscending) {
            NSLog(@"morning");      
    }
   else  if ([afternoonStart compare:resultTime]==NSOrderedAscending & [resultTime compare:afternoonEnd]==NSOrderedAscending) {
                NSLog(@"aftrnon..."); 
            }
   else  if ([eveningStart compare:resultTime]==NSOrderedAscending & [resultTime compare:eveningEnd]==NSOrderedAscending) {
                NSLog(@"evening");    
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"nit time");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort and feedback @balu , but it's still getting me to afternoon when it's 12:55 AM at my place at the time of me writing it

Comment: @sunnyChopper:12:55 means that afternoon so we have to Give PM in the place of AM then you will get whatever you want.

Comment: @sunnyChopper: sorry for that ,12:55 AM,in NSDate format it gives 00:55 AM ,so in this way you are getting correct result.

Comment: You should really try your code or know that it is working. "May be" is not working IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the *NSDateComponents* to get only the hours and minutes of the *NSDate* objects that you are comparing. See the official documentation of *NSDateComponents* to figure out how to use it.

Then you compare the *NSDate* objects using one of the following methods:

```
- (NSDate *)earlierDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate
- (NSDate *)laterDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate
- (BOOL)isEqualToDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate
```

You should never use NSString when comparing dates.