# Switching background according to time

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

So I've looked around stack overflow for how to switch background image according to current time with IF statements & NSDateComponents:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
//AM
NSInteger Hour06 = 6; //1EarlyMorning
NSInteger Hour08 = 8; //2Morning
NSInteger Hour11 = 11; //3LateMorning
//PM
NSInteger Hour12 = 12; //4Afternoon
NSInteger Hour16 = 16; //5LateAfternoon
NSInteger Hour18 = 18; //6Evening
NSInteger Hour20 = 20; //7LateEvening
NSInteger Hour21 = 21; //8Night
NSInteger Hour23 = 23; //9LateNight


if (components.hour < Hour18)
{
    self.backgroundImage = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"6Evening"];
    self.backgroundImage.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
    self.backgroundImage.zPosition = 0.0; //Default bottom position

    [self addChild:self.backgroundImage];
}
```

But the image doesn't change. I've read this [Changing background according to time - Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995103/changing-background-according-to-time-objective-c) & it didn't help either. Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: something's a little confusing with your code - can you show more of it ? what is self ? a UIView ?

Comment: A yes, I forgot to mention this is being done in an SKScene, so an SKView (Sprite Kit game).

Comment: did you mean : if (component.hour > Hour18) ... by any chance

Comment: Yes :D I also posted the answer below if anyone will need help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My self & YvesLeBorg FOUND THE ANSWER! The following works if you're using SKView's due to Sprite Kit:

```
-(void)background
{

    NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
    NSInteger Hour18 = 18; //6Evening


    if (components.hour > Hour18)
    {
        self.backgroundImage = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"6Evening"];
        self.backgroundImage.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
        self.backgroundImage.zPosition = 0.0; //Default bottom position

        [self addChild:self.backgroundImage];
    }
}
```